# Netsuite - Add Select options in client script

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a sublist in the record and a custom select field in the main. What I want is when I add a line in the sublist, load the record from that line, take some info from there and add them as options to the custom select field. All those I want them in a client script. I think in validate line event or otherwise. I have tried addSelectOptions but it throws 'SSS_NOT_YET_SUPORTED'. 
Also the select field is not sourced from anywhere

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

var fieldObject = currentRecordObject.getField({
    fieldId: 'custpage_selecttestfield'
});

// Insert a new option.

fieldObject .insertSelectOption({
    value: 'Option1',
    text: 'Test1'
});

Answer (score 0):

There are two "Field" api's (using suitescript 2.x) - one on the 'currentRecord' module, and one on the 'ui/serverWidget' module.  Insert is used on the former, and add is used on the latter.

For the currentRecord module (from client script context):

```
 if (scriptContext.fieldId === 'custpage_bdcvalue')
 {
      let currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;
      let bdcField = currentRecord.getField({ fieldId: 'custpage_bdcselectvalue', });
 
      bdcField.removeSelectOption({ value: null, }); // clears all options
      // bdcField.removeSelectOption({ value: 1, });    // removes the option with that key (value).
 
      bdcField.insertSelectOption({ value: '', text: '', isSelected: false, });
      bdcField.insertSelectOption({ value: '2', text: 'New option', isSelected: false, });
 }
```

For the ui/serverWidget module (on a suitelet or restlet, etc):

```
 let BDCSelectValueField = form.addField({
      id: 'custpage_bdcselectvalue',
      type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
      label: 'BDC Select Value',
      container: 'RetrievedDataEntry',
 });

 BDCSelectValueField.addSelectOption({ value: '', text: '', isSelected: true, });
```